# Find Lowest Value in CSV File Below A Certain Cell and Output to Excel Cell

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am looking to take data from a CSV file and check for the lowest value under a certain heading.

I would then like to write that file to an excel file within a certain cell.

As an example:

### |18| Distance( ft) | DTF-RL |

### |19|  69.63636364  |31.05373|

### |20|  69.81818182  |30.85291|

### |21|  70.61818182  |31.85291|

The value of interest would be 30.85291, the lowest value in the range.

I would like to write that value to a specific cell within an excel document
I would then like to write the value next to it (the distance) in another cell within the same excel document.

I have very little programming experience and wanted to reduce a redundant task. I have no code as of yet, any direction would be much appreciated.

How can I implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: VTC - *How can I implement this?* - please post the code you've built to try to accomplish this and where it's not doing what you expect it to. We can help you tweak it to get it to work, but most likely no one will write it for you.

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to write it for me, but I am looking for some direction of literature. I have very little programming experience and wanted to reduce a redundant task. I have no code as of yet.

Comment: That would be a very straightforward macro. Just read any intro to vba article, learn how to record a macro, and record yourself sorting the table on DTF-RL column, and copying and pasteing the data where you want. That will give you a basic macro, which you can edit to make it work for different use cases. Good luck.

Comment: @JamesHayek - Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will help you understand the scope of what SO assists with in programming, since you are not likely to get much help with this question.